# Не работает передача в bottomsheetdialogfragmemt

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Метод передачи в фрагмент из активити

```
holder.texttovarprice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        TovarBottomOpisFragment tovarBottomOpisFragment=new TovarBottomOpisFragment();
        tovarBottomOpisFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),tovarBottomOpisFragment.getTag());
        Bundle data=new Bundle();
        data.putString("ProductTime",model.getProductTime());
        tovarBottomOpisFragment.setArguments(data);
        tovarBottomOpisFragment.setArguments(data);
        fragmentTransaction.replace().commit();
    }
});
```

Прием

```
getArguments().getString("ProductTime")
```

В фрагменте ничего не приходит равно нулю. Как переделать?

Comment: Вы что-станное делаете. Во первых транзакция, кажется, ничего не делает и не нужна. Во вторых вы аргументы после показа диалога задаëте, а надо до

Answer (score 0):

```
holder.texttovarprice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        TovarBottomOpisFragment tovarBottomOpisFragment=new TovarBottomOpisFragment();
        Bundle data=new Bundle();
        data.putString("ProductTime",model.getProductTime());
        // сначала передаём аргументы
        tovarBottomOpisFragment.setArguments(data);
        // потом показываем диалог
        tovarBottomOpisFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),tovarBottomOpisFragment.getTag());
    }
});
```